# Where is `zsh:command not found: important` coming from

Tags: zsh

I recently updated ZSH and now I'm seeing a `zsh:command not found: important` output whenever I do any command in the terminal.

```sh
❯ ls
...(lists all files)
zsh: command not found: important
```

```sh
❯ echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n'
/usr/local/opt/postgresql@10/bin
/Users/skube/.nvm/versions/node/v10.18.1/bin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
zsh: command not found: important
```

Where the heck is `important`?

Comment: Possibly a command substitution in `$PS1` which controls the display of the prompt

Comment: And "important" might not be the command but possibly one of its argument, e.g. when the command is variabilized (`$log_cmd important $log_msg` with unset `$log_cmd` would produce your error message)

Comment: What does `echo $PS1` reveal?

Comment: Yep, `echo $PS1` did in fact reveal where the `important` was coming from—the git branch name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was something silly. I was in a `git` branch that had been erroneously named with a quoted `important`.

```sh
❯ git br
* Some-`important`-work
  master
```

Interestingly, I could switch to this branch within VSCode, but not in Terminal. Also, in Terminal the branch displayed without `important` in the branch name, unit it was revealed as @lurker suggested with `echo $PS1`.